# Cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of null

Tags: angularjs

I keep getting this error in my program when I destroy my own scopes. I tracked it down to this while loop within angular:

```
if (!(next = (current.$$childHead || (current !== target && current.$$nextSibling)))) {
    while(current !== target && !(next = current.$$nextSibling)) {
        current = current.$parent;
    }
}
```

I've also managed to replicate it in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kEyqz/1/

It's pretty easy to set up, on an element I wire up a click event and then $broadcast that it was clicked followed by an $apply.

In a separate directive (with a child scope) I listen in on that event, and if I see it, I destroy the child scope. Doing so produces the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of null
```

This is just a small example of what I'm trying to accomplish in my code.

Console logging right before current = current.$parent results in the scope having no $parent (it is set to null).

I can add the lines:

```
if(!current){
    break;
}
```

After the current = current.$parent, but i'd have to maintain it if I switch angular versions (not ideal)

Comment: Seems to be a known bug: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1627

Comment: That bug was marked fixed 9 months ago and this question is about a problem that still happens with current Angular 1.0.8.

Comment: Do you see this problem destroying your own scopes you created itself? The example in your jsFiddle is destroying a scope that Angular created for your directive. If I change it to create and then destroy a different scope, I don't see this problem. http://jsfiddle.net/kEyqz/2/

Comment: The problem is relating to the `$broadcast` logic since the directive is destroyed and the DFS algorithm should be notified to ignore the directive node. I think your fix is ok and you should submit it as a patch.

Comment: Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/kEyqz/7/, is that what you want?

Comment: I need to listen in on the $destroy event.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for http://jsfiddle.net/jw99Lj7t/ ?

You were `$destroy`'ing the `$scope` durgin `digest` cycle - that was causing the error.

I don't belive that this is a `bug` since this is how `digest` cycle is implemented (it loops over the list of `$scopes` checking if something has changed, and we can't remove the scopes from that list as it is "already in use").

Resolving this issue, may introduce a lot of complexities and since `digest` must be very fast, it's better to just find a different way for the thing you are doing.

Comment: That is a last case resort. I already have that piece of code as a failsafe currently.

Comment: @MathewBerg Last case resort, I think you'll find this is the only way, i have come across this error many of times and the actual problem is that you have destroyed the scope but angular is still working with that scope and thinks it still exists so its checking values on it. `setTimeout` is the only way, it makes sure angular is finished before you destroy the scope. @g00fy in your demo you're using `setTimeout` but you haven't mentioned it anywhere in your code, **+1** if you do.

Comment: My solution uses $timeout instead, but basically the same thing.

Comment: @MathewBerg why would you use `$timeout`? That is for setting a timeout and within that timeout you want to work with the scope, when you don't, you wan't to destroy it.

Comment: With the setTimeout method, you need to run a $apply() afterwards if other things are listening in for that scope to be destroyed. By wrapping it in the $timeout I just make sure it occures later in the cycle, which is after the broadcast has finished (where the problem lies)

Comment: Thank you! Using $timeout solved this problem for me.

Comment: I also ran into this issue and fixed it using a `setTimeout` (no need to digest the scope)

Comment: I've since gone back and accepted your answer @g00fy but I think it'd be better if you used angulars $timeout instead of a setTimeout.

Comment: I've edited it to include the $timeout in the fiddle